# Https GET request passes in Postman and browser but fails in code

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to obtain a JSON via a rest API using, targeting .Net 4.5
I've tried various methods in code, but the all end up in me getting:

> "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
> transportstream" .

the exact same URL works via browser and Postman.

So far, I've tried using .Net's WebClient, HttpClient and HttpWebRequest with identical results. I've tried comparing requests between Postman and my code (via RequestBin), but even when they were identical, I still kept getting back:

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
> transport

My current code is using HttpWebRequest, but every solution will do.

I've played around with all of the security protocols, some of them will cause the API to return `404` and some will cause the server to return

> "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
> transport stream".

Here's my current code:

```
public string GetCityStreets()
{
    var url = "https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=a7296d1a-f8c9-4b70-96c2-6ebb4352f8e3&q=26";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string jsonResponse;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
         jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

In my current code, the exception is thrown when the request is actually made: `request.GetResponse()`.
What I need, essentially, is to get the JSON from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` **before** you initalize the request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` 
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
```

If you're on Windows 7. On Windows 10, you should only need `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault`.

---

**Note**: To enable **`TLS1.3`** (it's available in both Windows 7 and Windows 10), If you don't use `.Net 4.8` or `.Net Core 3.0`, since there's no enumerator for it, you can set it with:

```
var secProtoTls13 = (SecurityProtocolType)12288;
```

---

Remove all the other `SecurityProtocolType` you have set there.

Setting the `User-Agent` header is also mandatory, otherwise you will receive a `404` (not found). Here's the FireFox header:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0";
```

**A note on the User-Agent header**: this specific site doesn't activate [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiEmfOxl9DjAhUxMuwKHWvmDQcQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHTTP_Strict_Transport_Security&usg=AOvVaw1fchZaueG6yXEG2yoTKmy1) (HSTS). But some sites do, when they *see* that the WebBrowser supports it. `HttpWebRequest` doesn't understand it, so it will simply wait for a response that never comes, since the Site is waiting for *interaction*.
You may want to use the `IE11` header instead.

Also add this other header:

```
 request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
```

Comment: that did it!, but with the combination of @mjwills answer. without the change in the user agent it still doesn't work. thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know it needs a User-Agent. I've tested it. Without it (btw, it's pretty common) the site refuses to preceed further and simply replies `404`.

Comment: See the note I added, about the User-Agent. You may find it important to debug an *undefined* connection  issue.

Answer (score 1):

The server side appears to be checking the user agent (presumably to stop bots and other code (like yours!) from hitting the endpoint). To bypass this, you will need to set the user agent to a value such that it thinks you are a web browser.

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36";
```

works, as an example.

*You may wish to consider setting the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` **just once** (at app startup) rather than on each request.*

Answer (score 0):

This works using HttpClient (.net 4.5 and up)

```
    var url = "https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=a7296d1a-f8c9-4b70-96c2-6ebb4352f8e3&q=26";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");
    Task<string> response =  client.GetStringAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
```

Think the server requires a user agent.

Comment: this also work, but only with adding   'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;' before the client is being created. Thanks!